# how to increase my shoulder width ? is it possible?

Tags: muscle-gain, growth

I am 19 yrs male. My shoulders are less width. my shoulder and waist not in golden ratio and suggest the exercise not including dumbbells and weight lifting because i also want to grow tall

Answer (score 2):

Weight lifting will not affect your general growth, including height, as long as you don't starve yourself.

If you want broader shoulders and a slimmer waist, do shoulder exercises and lose fat.

Answer (score 2):

I have a the same problem I usually do lots of dumbbell side raises on low weight just to get the shoulder pumped, this exercise really adds mass to the side of the shoulder (1 muscle of 3). Also the wide shoulders are an illusion created by a thin waist so you tend to look broader if you have a small waste. So basically loose the love handle :).

But I must urge you please be careful, shoulder injuries are common in the bodybuilding community. This can be seen by multiple posts in the forum.

Comment: Does  it really work the user

Comment: It worked for me. I have shoulder issues so I warm up shoulders before every upper body day as well. The dumb-side raises do work just watch an instructional video and do use a light weight or you land up swinging weights around aimlessly. As for the love handles cardio and low GI carbs. It helps to find fun cardio stuff like (and I know I'm gonna get burned for this) crossfit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between safely lifting weights and stunting growth, so no need to worry about affecting height. Plus, at 19 you are very likely almost as tall as you will be for the rest of your life.

The three important muscle groups to target for broad shoulders would be:

- Deltoids, the "caps" on the top of your arms, think of where your sleeve is sewn onto your shirt. Side lateral raise will work these.
- Traps, the muscle that looks like the side/back of your neck, is important as well. You can exercise this by doing shrugs (be it with dumbell or barbell, or machine).
- Shoulder/Upper Back Area, the muscles surrounding your shoulder blades. Military press is a good exercise for this area.